Can I use Istio along with Dapr?
Istio is widely used for mesh control, to control fine grained traffics and to utilize kubernetes.
Dapr is good for cross-service interactions, helping with distributed orchistration.
How can I combine Dapr with Istio in practice, to bring both better DX and high accessibility?

I'm a Dapr maintainer. Yes, you can absolutely use Istio and Dapr together. I know of many workloads that do this. Essentially you'd want to disable mTLS in Dapr and make sure that you use Istio excluded ports to allow Dapr to talk to its control plane.
